# Getting tokenized path matched by route template (ASP.NET Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to **getting the fragment** of the original request URI that matches a route template i.e. `https://apim.example.com/api/v1/controller/[a/{id}/b]` with the `[..]` being the fragment matched by the route template; the path is available from this.Request.Path but is the fragment available sepeartely?

I've read (all) the docs, checked all properties of the `HttpRequest` instance and didn't find the actual tokenized fragment (only the meta data describing the controller/action params like naming etc.). I need the fragment as part of a proxy API (with pattern specific handlers).

### Proxy API

I'm writing a proxy service in `ASP.NET Core 3.1` (sits behind an `Azure API Management` instance) that maps a subset of a remote API and applies a security scheme on top. The proxy recognizes a set of known route signatures in order to apply the security scheme according to requested resource(s).

Request sent to Azure API Management (e.g.):

```
https://apim.example.com/api/v1/organizations/{id}/{*path}
```

Request to proxy as forwarded by Azure API Management:

```
https://proxy.example.com/api/v1/proxy/v1/organizations/{id}/{*path}
```

It's worth mentioning that both the proxy and the remote API provide an invididualized versioning scheme (hence the fully qualified proxy path from Azure API Management). The proxy is implemented with `ASP.NET Core 3.1 routing` as can be seen from the following snippet:

```cs
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class ProxyController : ControllerBase
{
    .. constructors and other members omitted for brevity

    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [HttpPut]
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("v1/organizations/{id:int}/{*path}")]
    public async Task OrganizationsAsync(int organizationID, string path, CancellationToken cancellation = default)
    {
        // would like to get the tokenized "v1/organizations/{id:int}/{*path}" fragment here

        var message = await this.service.HandleAsync(this.Request, path, cancellation);

        await this.handler.CopyAsync(this.HttpContext, message);
    }
}
```

In `OrganizationsAsync` I'm looking for a dynamic approach to getting the `v1/organizations/{id:int}/{*path}` fragment instead of having to predefine the various base URIs of the controller (as can be seen from the following example).

### Using a predefined controller URI

```cs
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class ProxyController : ControllerBase
{
    .. constructors and other members omitted for brevity

    private readonly string baseUri = "api/v1/proxy";

    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [HttpPut]
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("v1/organizations/{id:int}/{*path}")]
    public async Task OrganizationsAsync(int organizationID, string path, CancellationToken cancellation = default)
    {
        var localpath = this.Request.Path.Value.Replace(this.baseUri, "");
        var message = await this.service.HandleAsync(this.Request, localpath, cancellation);

        await this.handler.CopyAsync(this.HttpContext, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the ASP.NET Core team, there's currently no API that provides the string fragment (or equivalent structure) matching just the route template signature.

I decided to create the fragment from the route values as can be seen from the following snippet:

```cs
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{apiVersion:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class ProxyController : ControllerBase
{
    .. constructors and other members omitted for brevity

    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [HttpPut]
    [HttpDelete]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("v{version:int}/organizations/{organizationID:int}/{*path}")]
    public async Task OrganizationsAsync(int version, int organizationID, string path, CancellationToken cancellation = default)
    {
        await this.HandleAsync($"v{version}/organizations/{organizationID}/{path}", cancellation);
    }
}
```